# ¿Por qué no obtengo ningún valor de predicción de mi modelo?

Tags: reactjs, machine-learning, tensorflow

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación en React que me permita subir una imagen y que, a partir de un modelo de Machine Learning me diga si lo que se ve en la foto es un lunar que puede ser malicioso o no.

La aplicación, por ahora, se ve algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La persona selecciona la imagen y esta se debe redimensionar para quedar de un tamaño de 150 x 150 (que es el tamaño que se utiliza para el modelo). El problema es que no me está imprimiendo lo que debería. De hecho, hay cosas que ni siquiera imprime.

El código que tengo es el siguiente. La parte principal de la aplicación es esta

```js
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import ImageUploader from './components/ImageUploader';
import ImagePreview from './components/ImagePreview';
import ProbabilityResult from './components/ProbabilityResult';
import { resizeImage } from './utils/imageUtils';

const App = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [probability, setProbability] = useState(null);

  const handleImageSelect = async (image) => {
    console.log("Seleccionó");
    setSelectedImage(image);
    const tensor = await imageToTensor(image);

    const result = await predict(tensor);

    console.log("resultado", result);
    setProbability(result);
  };

  const handleImageUpload = async () => {
    if(selectedImage != null){
      console.log("image", selectedImage)
      console.log("Probabilidad", probability)
      
      setProbability(probability);
    }
    
  };

  const imageToTensor = async (image) => {
    const tensor = await resizeImage(image, 150, 150);
    return tensor;
  };

  const predict = async (tensor) => {
    tf.enableDebugMode();
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel("/public/model/model.json");

    model.summary();
    
    const tensor4d = tf.tensor4d(tensor);
    const result = model.predict(tensor4d);

    const probabilities = result.dataSync();

    console.log("probabilidades", probabilities);

    return probabilities;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>Aplicación de Detección de Cáncer de Piel</h1>
      </header>
      <ImageUploader onImageSelect={handleImageSelect} />
      <ProbabilityResult probability={probability} />
      <button onClick={handleImageUpload}>Realizar Predicción</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Aquí está la forma en la que se carga la imagen

```js
import React from 'react';

const ImagePreview = ({ image }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Imagen:</h2>
      {image && <img src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} alt="Preview" />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImagePreview;
```

Y este es el código que utilizo para "redimensionar" la imagen y convertirla en un tensor, que a la final es lo que necesito para que mi modelo se entrene.

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

export const resizeImage = (file, newWidth, newHeight) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = newWidth;
      canvas.height = newHeight;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

      const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas).toFloat().expandDims();
      resolve(tensor);
    };

    if (file instanceof Blob) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        img.src = e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else if (typeof file === 'string') {
      img.src = file;
    }
  });
};
```

Después de iniciar la aplicación, subir una imagen y presionar "Realizar predicción", el resultado que obtengo es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo qué es lo que está sucediendo. No sé si quizá estoy realizando algo mal con el modelo o con las llamadas asíncronas porque, como se ve, hay un par de prints (en la aplicación principal) que no se están viendo (el console.log("resultado", result)) y tampoco entiendo qué sucede allí.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Es complicado depurar este proyecto pero en general esas funciones `async` (handleImageSelect...etc) deben estar envueltas en `useEffect`